# Using movie names in a game

Tags: copyright

I am working out a concept of a game where I want to refer to movies. However, I am unsure if I can just refer to the real movie titles in the game or if I should change them slightly so that it becomes a parody of the movie for liablility / copyright reasons.

I know it is a bit on the risky side when you are using brands etc, but can I be held acountable for indirect damage to the sales of their movie?

Does this change when I use an API from a website (f.e. imdb / TheMovieDatabase)?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the context of how you're using the names? Using them as real-world trivia questions & answers might have different considerations from using them in your story or environmental design.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When does a Reference become Copyright Infringement?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/178681/when-does-a-reference-become-copyright-infringement)

Comment: Titles aren't copyrighted, they are trademarked. Trademark law is different from copyright law.

Comment: And in fact, [they aren't even usually trademarked](https://www.klemchuk.com/ip-law-trends/trademark-copyright-mpaa-when-can-you-protect-movies-titles). If they are, then you can check if your use of them is a [Trademark Infringement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark_infringement) or not. (Note I'm not a lawyer and this isn't legal advice.)